# Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'PropertySearch'

Tags: .net, json, web-services, deserialization

I am having a weservice method,

```
public string SearchProperties(string pPropertySearch, string pSort)
    {
        string[] _propSearch = pPropertySearch.Split(',');
        string searchType = (_propSearch)[_propSearch.Length - 1];
        List<Property> returnResults = new List<Property>();
        try
        {
            PropertySearch _MyPropertySearch = (PropertySearch)JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(pPropertySearch, typeof(PropertySearch));
            returnResults = PropertyDALC.SearchPropertyNew(_MyPropertySearch, pSort, searchType, 25);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        string output = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(returnResults);

        return output;
    }
```

PropertySearch.cs,

```
[Serializable]
public class PropertySearch
{
private string userId;
private string sessionId;

private string priceMin;
private string priceMax;


public string UserId
{
    get { return userId; }
    set { userId = value; }
}
public string SessionId
{
    get { return sessionId; }
    set { sessionId = value; }
}

public string PriceMin
{
    get { return priceMin; }
    set { priceMin = value; }
}
public string PriceMax
{
    get { return priceMax; }
    set { priceMax = value; }
}
public string BedsMin
{
    get { return bedsMin; }
    set { bedsMin = value; }
}         
}
```

I have given the string "pPropertySearch" as:

```
 "0000-0000","gghuk","6666","8888"
```

when clicked on InVoke button , the webservice is invoked and near this line

```
" PropertySearch _MyPropertySearch = (PropertySearch)JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(pPropertySearch, typeof(PropertySearch));"
```

it is giving this exception,

```
 "Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'PropertySearch'"
```

What's wrong with this code. Please correct me.

Am I passing string in wrong format? Please help. 
  I don't know these serialization, deserialization concepts in webservice.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to deserialize with invalid json. A good place to check your json format is [JsonLint.com](http://jsonlint.com). You will want your json object to look more like this:

```
{
    "UserId": 1,
    "SessionId": 1,
    "PriceMin": 1,
    "PriceMax": 1,
    "BedsMin": 1
}
```

The issue you are having is you are passing a comma delimited string. The deserializer does not know which values to map to which fields.